# DATA.each_line - not returning header_names

Tags: ruby

```
header_names = []
DATA.each_line { |e|
    if e =~ /\|/
        return header_names
    end
}
p header_names

__END__
blah blah
|A|B|C|
|1|1|1|
|2|2|2|
```

p header_names - why it does not print the array header_names ?

Comment: Does the constant `DATA` hold a string or, as @Stefan would lead us to believe, it is the pre-defined constant `File::DATA`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland _"lead us to believe"_ — you made my day ^_^

Comment: In my code example - before keyword 'return' - I forgot to split current line by '|'. But even after correcting my code - I still cannot get data in 'header_names' (expecting A, B and C).

Comment: Solution to my question:   header_names = DATA.find { |e| e =~ /\|/ }

Answer (score 3):

> `p header_names` - why it does not print the array header_names?

You have a *toplevel return*, i.e. a `return` outside a method. When Ruby encounters that line, it stops evaluating the script and the program silently ends. It's roughly equivalent to:

```
DATA.each_line { |e|
  if e =~ /\|/
    exit              # <- if the program exits here
  end                 #
}                     #
p header_names        # <- this line won't be reached
```

Maybe you wanted to [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) the first line containing `|`:

```
header_names = DATA.find { |e| e =~ /\|/ }
p header_names
```

which will print:

```
"|A|B|C|\n"
```

Comment: I believe you mean `DATA.each_line.find { |e| e =~ /\|/ }`. Perhaps  `DATA[/^.*\|.*$/]` (newline chopped).

Comment: @CarySwoveland `DATA` is an instance of `File` which includes `Enumerable`. And the inherited [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/IO.html#method-i-each) method already yields lines.

Comment: I assumed `DATA` was a string. It's perhaps worth mentioning that `grep` can be used to get all the lines containing a pipe.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `DATA` is actually a `File` object for the current script with its position set right after `__END__`. You could call `DATA.rewind ; DATA.read` to get the whole file content ;-)

Comment: How do you know that `DATA` does not equal `"__END__\nblah blah\n|A|B|C|\n|1|1|1|\n|2|2|2|\n"`? It might also be noted that no elements are added to `header_names` in the OP's code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `DATA` is one of Ruby's [pre-defined constants](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants), that's the way it works. Sorry, I assumed you were aware of it :-)

Comment: Only someone who actually wrote Ruby code for a living would know that. Nevertheless, my question stands.